# How do you show a random string in Flutter

Tags: flutter, random

I am  beginner in dart with flutter and I need to display a random string on the app screen.

I know how to get a random string but I am facing problems in trying to display it on the app screen.

So how do I display this string on the user's screen? Sorry, I am only a beginner and can't find this anywhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Text widget with the string as the content.

For Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Random String is $yourstring'), // use $ sign to use content of a variable
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```